# The program can't start because MSVCP100.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dll, mega

Hi I'm getting this error when I try to start MegaSync from mega.co.nz

Installation worked, but the program doesn't start

What could be the issue

Comment: Get from Stackoverflow http://www.steptoinstall.com/msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-wamp-server-install.html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install

Answer (score 19):

It would seem that your program is 32-bit, but didn't install its needed 32-bit libraries on your 64-bit OS.

`MSVCP100.dll`, is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime libraries, so ensure you install the 32-bit versions of those C++ runtime libraries.

You can get them from Microsoft here: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555)

You may also want to install the 64-bit version as well, just in case: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)