# The program can't start because MSVCP100.dll is missing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Hi I'm getting this error when I try to start MegaSync from mega.nz
Installation worked, but the program doesn't start

I tried solutions from here https://superuser.com/a/803291/475313 and from here https://superuser.com/a/827889/475313 but they did not help at all. So may be there is another issue related to Windows 10?

I also wrote to Mega's support, but still got no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you're using should work. I have successfully installed and run MEGAsync under Windows 10.

Note that MEGAsync takes care of installing the Visual C++ 2010 runtime itself when you run setup. Evidently this was not successful in your case.

Starting again from a clean slate should fix it:

1. Uninstall MEGAsync
2. Uninstall the Visual C++ 2010 runtime (all versions, in case you have an old version present that's confusing the MEGAsync setup)
3. Reinstall MEGAsync

Comment: Thanks, deleting and installing (not repairing/reinstalling) of everything (Mega app and all Visual C++ 20xx) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This Microsoft post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-performance/msvcp100dll-missing/9a687c31-0619-4ee9-b511-020985e29b5f?auth=1), as well as confirming that MSVCP100.dll is part of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package which you've tried reinstalling, also says you should run this command to check/fix your system files:

```
sfc /scannow
```

(run as administrator).

If it still doesn't work after applying the recommended actions, right-click the disk in File Explorer and from Properties, Tools press the Check button under Error checking. After a restart this will check your disk and you can then retry the other things once you know your disk is in good shape.

Comment: I did everything you suggested and still have the same error.

Comment: I checked the disk, there were no errors and I reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ runtime libraries.

Comment: So, what could it be?